# Pagination count wrong Cakephp 1.2

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-1.3

I had auction bid list (debit for each auction was equal 1). I changed View code for "Debit" for showing "Auction Id" count. (you can see pic.). 
But now I have problem with pagination. It has to show 26 but you can see 93. 
I want to show result like in picture but with correct pagination.

Here is my code

In Controller:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array('Bid.user_id' => $user_id),
    'limit' => 100,
    'order' => array('Bid.created' => 'desc'),
    'contain' => array('Auction' => array('Product'))
);

$this->set('bids', $this->paginate());
```

In Model: override paginateCount()

```
function paginateCount($conditions = null, $recursive = 0, $extra = array()) {
    $sql = "
        SELECT user_id,
               auction_id,
               description,
               debit,
               COUNT( * ) AS my_auct,
               `credit`,
               `created`
          FROM `bids`
         WHERE `user_id` = {$this->User->id}
         GROUP BY auction_id, credit
    ";

    $this->recursive = $recursive;
    $results = $this->query($sql);

    return count($results);
}
```

How can fix this issue only in controller (not using paginateCount) and put this query result into View (now I made calculating in View).

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Im not sure why you expect 26 results when you set `'limit' => 100`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Here my code in controller

```
$this->paginate = array('conditions' => array('Bid.user_id' => $user_id),'fields' => array('COUNT(auction_id) as my_auct', 'Bid.*'), 'group' => array('Bid.auction_id', 'Bid.credit'), 'limit' => 10000, 'order' => array('Bid.created' => 'desc'), 'contain' => array('Auction' => array('Product')));
```

I found paginateCount function [here](http://www.mainelydesign.com/blog/view/best-paginatecount-cakephp-with-group-by-support) and added in model:

```
public function paginateCount($conditions = null, $recursive = 0, $extra = array()) {
                $conditions = compact('conditions');
                if ($recursive != $this->recursive) {
                    $conditions['recursive'] = $recursive;
                }
                unset( $extra['contain'] );
                $count = $this->find('count', array_merge($conditions, $extra));

                    if (isset($extra['group'])) {
                        $count = $this->getAffectedRows();
                    }

                return $count;
            }
```

Only thing I can't show in "Credit" column are all values (when I grouped by auction_id and credit, it shows to me only one 15 and 100). I want to show all values in credit column

Any ideas?